# how to change permission file?

Tags: android

I located file from server into internal or external storage. when I copy from imported file to original db file, I've got error "java.nio.channels.NonReadableChannelException"   I think it is because the imported file permission is -rw-------.

I'm trying to copy db file from server to android app. because when changing phone, backup and restore will be needed. so I completed backup and restore, and the upload is not problem. but when I restore the file, I can't read the file because of permission although the server file(restore) is saved in storage.

```
case R.id.backup:

                RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part multipartBody =MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.getName(),requestFile);

                Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall = retrofitInterface.upload(multipartBody);
                responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        Log.d("Success", "success "+response.code());
                        Log.d("Success", "success "+response.message());

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
                        Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
                    }
                });
                break;
            case R.id.recovery:
                responseBodyCall = retrofitInterface.download("location");
                responseBodyCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        Log.d("Success", "success "+response.code());
                        Log.d("Success", "success "+response.message());
                        Log.d("Success", "downloaded");

                        String sdcardPath = null;
                        String sdcardStat = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                        if(sdcardStat.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                            sdcardPath =getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
                        }
                        Log.d("TAG", sdcardPath);
                        //boolean isSuccess = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());
                        //if(isSuccess) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        File newFile = new File(sdcardPath+"/location");
                        try {

                            if (!newFile.exists()) {
                                newFile.createNewFile();
                            }
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                            fos.write(response.body().bytes());
                            fos.close();
                            Log.d("TAG",newFile.length()+"");

                            try {


                                //file is original db file in app located in /data/user/0/com.jakchang.savelocation/databases/location
                                Log.d("TAG",file.getPath()+"");
                                // newFile is imported db file from server located in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.jakchang.savelocation/files/location
                                Log.d("TAG",newFile.getPath()+"");

                                FileChannel dst = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
                                FileChannel src = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
                                src.transferTo(0, src.size(), dst); //this is error because I read    -rw-------  imported file to original file
                                //dst.transferTo(0, dst.size(), src);       //this is not error because I read -rw-rw---- original file to imported file
                                src.close();
                                dst.close();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Successful!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                            }


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("failure", "message = " + t.getMessage());
                        Log.d("failure", "cause = " + t.getCause());
                    }
                });
```

I have to do "src.transferTo(0, src.size(), dst);" that is imported file for original db file copying.

```
error 

2019-12-22 01:02:14.224 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err: java.nio.channels.NonReadableChannelException
2019-12-22 01:02:14.224 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferTo(FileChannelImpl.java:631)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at com.jakchang.savelocation.MainActivity$6.onResponse(MainActivity.java:494)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6986)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
2019-12-22 01:02:14.225 26879-26879/com.jakchang.savelocation W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
```

Comment: You cannot change the permission. Most likely, your problem has to do with something else.

Comment: what's the something else? when I test    FileChannel dst = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
                                FileChannel src = new FileOutputStream(newFile).getChannel();
                                src.transferTo(0, src.size(), dst);
                                src.close();
                                dst.close();  it was not working. because src is "-rw-rw----" but  when I change the two variable, it was working. because src is"-rw-------" and dst is "-rw-rw----".

Comment: "what's the something else?" -- since we do not have a full [mcve], that is difficult to say. For example, we do not know what "it was not working" means in programming terms. Looking at permission bits in an Android device is rarely useful, as those bits depend entirely on the Linux user, and each app has its own user (as do things like the developer tools). Android uses its own permission system (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, etc.) that controls the access.

Comment: um... so is it impossible to copy from server file to original file in app?

Comment: We do not know exactly what you mean by "copy from server file to original file", let alone how you are trying to do it. You might consider asking a Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve], showing all the relevant code and explaining in detail what "it was not working" means.

Comment: I edited my question. I wish u understand my question.

Comment: You are not copying anything, as all of your copy code is commented out. If we assume that you were trying `src.transferTo(0, src.size(), dst)`, we still do not know what "it was not working" means. For example, if you are crashing, look in Logcat for the stack trace. We also do not know where `file` points to.

Comment: thank u for your help, I added more details..

Comment: I added some code    int maxCount = 1024*1024*200;
                                long size = src.size();
                                long position = 0;
                                System.out.println("size:"+size);
                                while (position < size) {
                                    position += src.transferTo(position, maxCount, dst);
                                }

                                src.close();
                                dst.close();   and no error. but data is not copied from imported file to original file....